# IOException when trying to run ffmpeg command on Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am using this library through gradle with Android Studio 3.6.

```
implementation 'com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg:FFmpegAndroid:0.2.5'
```

This is path of input and output file.

```
String VideoIn = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/Ab.mp4";
String VideoOut = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/Ab1.avi";
```

This is code where I load ffmpeg and try to execute command to convert an mp4 into avi. (Same command i use on windows to do this task). But it say IOException (No such file or directory) although input file is present in Download folder.

```
private void convert(String VideoIn, String VideoOut) {
    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                super.onFailure();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                super.onSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        ffmpeg.execute("-i " + VideoIn + " " + VideoOut, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.e(TAG, message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.e(TAG, message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e(TAG, message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStart called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFinish called");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is log data for your to understand. I am not that expert in that so I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code. Path is correct and file is there. Maybe I am calling this command wrong or what?

I searched google and stack overflow much but nothing helped me solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
04-20 12:08:26.050 12696-12696/com.example.myapplication E/Video to Mp3: Input File Path: 
/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab.mp4
04-20 12:08:26.050 12696-12696/com.example.myapplication E/Video to Mp3: Output File Path: 
/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab1.avi
04-20 12:08:26.050 12696-12696/com.example.myapplication E/Video to Mp3: Device not supported
04-20 12:08:26.050 12696-12696/com.example.myapplication E/Video to Mp3: onStart called
04-20 12:08:26.084 12696-13027/com.example.myapplication E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: 
/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab.mp4 
/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab1.avi
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab.mp4, /storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab1.avi] Working Directory: null Environment: null
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:186)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:259)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:202)
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:186) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:259) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:202) 
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10) 
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38) 
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) 
04-20 12:08:26.084 12696-12696/com.example.myapplication E/Video to Mp3: onFinish called
```

Comment: The log is self explanatory `IOException: No such file or directory`. You are passing a path which doesn't exist.

Comment: But that file is there in Download folder. I have triple checked. I am using Huawei device. Any idea to test path with something before executing command? Or any sample code for ffmpeg commands to convert a file from mp4 to avi which is in download folder?

Comment: did you ask/request runtime permissions?

Comment: Yes. I requested permission to write external storage and I tested it on Huawei mate s device by giving it storage permission. I create directory using code and directory successfully created.

Comment: What does `VideoIn` return? Create a log - `Log.e("VideoIn", "path = "+VideoIn")`

Comment: Here is log info. 04-28 21:33:36.307 1254-1254/com.example.myapplication E/VideoIn: path = /storage/emulated/0/Download/Ab.mp4

Comment: Are you targeting API 29?

Comment: Yes. My targetSdkVersion is 29.

Comment: Add the following in your Manifest(under application) `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Comment: Sorry I was busy in another project. Added this line in manifest. Result is same. IOException: No such file or directory. Still I can create directory and the Ab.mp4 file exists in Download folder. Couldn't understand why this is happening.

Comment: @RashidFaheem did you found any solution? I'm getting same error